# How to flatten array types inside pandas dataframe with an sklearn transformer?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with both scalar columns and array columns, e.g.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "scalar": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "array": [[10,20], [30,40], [50, 60], [70, 80]],
})
```

I want to write a sklearn transformer to flatten it, so that

```py
transformer = ???
transformer.fit_transform(df)
===>
[[1 10 20
  2 30 40
  3 50 60
  4 70 80]]
```

How might I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is a stateless transformation, you can use [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) to define a transformer from a function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "scalar": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "array": [[10,20], [30,40], [50, 60], [70, 80]],
})


def flatten_df_rows(df):
    def flatten(row):
        # flatten lists recursively 
        for val in row:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                yield from flatten(val)
            else:
                yield val
    # flatten each row of the df recursively           
    return np.array([list(flatten(row)) for row in df.values.tolist()])

transform = FunctionTransformer(flatten_df_rows)
out = transform.fit_transform(df)
```

Output:

```
>>> out 

array([[ 1, 10, 20],
       [ 2, 30, 40],
       [ 3, 50, 60],
       [ 4, 70, 80]])
```